# fscanf / fscanf_s overwriting arrays

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use fscanf to load in some default values for an array of structs, which looks something like

```
#define NUMPIECES 21
typedef struct{
    short map[5][5];
    short rotation;
    short reflection;
} mytype_t;
typedef struct{
    mytype_t p[NUMPIECES];
} mytypelist_t;
```

The data is stored in a textfile as the following (repeated several times with different values):

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 2
[...]
```

I'm reading in the values with fscanf / fscanf_s (tried both) as below:

```
mytypelist_t list;
FILE * f;
[...]
for (i=0; i<NUMPIECES; i++){
    for (j=0; j<5; j++){
        fscanf(f,"%d%d%d%d%d", &(list->p[i].map[j][0]),
                                &(list->p[i].map[j][1]),
                                &(list->p[i].map[j][2]),
                                &(list->p[i].map[j][3]),
                                &(list->p[i].map[j][4]));
    }
    fscanf(f,"%d %d", &(list->p[i].rotations), &(list->p[i].reflection));
}
```

However, VS2012 threw up an exception at the end, saying the list was corrupted. Debugging has shown that after reading the first four lines of the above example text, the "map" part of the struct contains the following

```
map = [ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
      [ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
      [ 0 0 1 0 0 ]
      [ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
      [ 0 X X X X ]
```

where X is an uninitialized value.

It appears as though fscanf is attempting to "null-terminate" my array of integers or somesuch, and is overwriting the first element of the subsequent row. I only discovered it because VS threw an exception on exit - data is read in perfectly otherwise (the additional 0's are overwritten by the next fscanf call).

Is this a byproduct of fscanf? Or do I have an error I'm overlooking?

(Compiling/Testing on VS2012)

Comment: You've declared `mytype_t.map` as 5x5, but your example text file is 4x5.  Is that a typo?  If not then that's your problem.  `fscanf()` is trying to read 5 integers from a line with only 2 available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think fscanf is trying to fill in ints while you're giving it pointers to shorts. fscanf doesn't know the actual type of the fields it's filling int; it relies on the format specifiers for that. I don't know of any "short" format specifier. So I would either change your data fields to ints, or scan into ints and then copy to the shorts in your data structures

Comment: `%hd` is the format specifier to match a `short *` argument to the `scanf` family of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `short` format specifier `"%hd"` and check the result of `fscanf()`

```
int cnt = fscanf(f,"%hd%hd%hd%hd%hd", &(list->p[i].map[j][0]),
    &(list->p[i].map[j][1]), &(list->p[i].map[j][2]),
    &(list->p[i].map[j][3]), &(list->p[i].map[j][4]));
if (cnt != 5) Handle_MissingData();
```

As data has 5 numbers per line, recommend reading *lines*, then scan.

```
char buf[5*22];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
int cnt = sscanf(buf,"%hd%hd%hd%hd%hd", &(list->p[i].map[j][0]),
    &(list->p[i].map[j][1]), &(list->p[i].map[j][2]),
    &(list->p[i].map[j][3]), &(list->p[i].map[j][4]));
if (cnt != 5) Handle_MissingData();
```

---

If on a system that does not have a format specifier for `short` ...

```
char buf[5*22];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
int tmp[5];
int cnt = sscanf(buf,"%d%d%d%d%d", 
    &tmp[0], &tmp[1], &tmp[2], &tmp[3], &tmp[4]);
for (i=0; i<cnt; i++)) {
  list->p[i].map[j][i] = tmp[i];
}
if (cnt != 5) Handle_MissingData();
```

Comment: Any benefits to using fgets+sscanf over fscanf for controlled and known inputs?

Comment: @wilcroft 1) With challenging inputs, especially strings that contain spaces, but not end-of-line, fgets/sscanf/strtok/strod etc is easier to code.  2) inputs are only "known" _after_ there are read not before.  incorporating error handling is simpler with `fgets()` vs `fscanf()`.

Comment: "known" inputs, in this case, refers to inputs predefined by me, so are guaranteed to match. I get adding the extra precautions for code parsing semi-generic user input.